# How to show a small preview of a UIScrollView content?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, calayer

I want to show a small preview of the current area being displayed of UIScrollView like Sublime text editor does.

Imagine that my UIScrollView size is 640x480, but the content is 640x960.

When I scroll I want to be able to show a small preview of the whole UIScrollView content in the top right corner, making possible for the user to understand which part of the UIScrollView he is actually looking at.

How do I achieve such thing?

CAReplicator?

CAScrollLayer?

I'm kind of lost here so any tips would be awesome.

Thanks,

With my best regards,

Nuno